# no puedo depurar mi web en android directamente con chrome usando developer tools

Tags: android, apache, ubuntu, chrome

chrome del portatil reconoce mi android pero cuando intento ver mi localhost de ubuntu en el chrome en android me dice esto la consola:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tengo que modificar el apache2.conf no?

```
<Directory /var/www/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from all (esto lo he añadido)
</Directory>
```

Comment: Estas intentando conectarte a la dirección **pública** de tu equipo ¿ verdad ? **No** a [localhost](http://127.0.0.1).

Comment: me he conectado ahora con mi ip y la consola me dice: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)

Comment: Esto último suena a problema de puertos o redirección del router.

Comment: pero si estoy usando directamente el movil con el portatil por cable. no puedo acceder a localhost, no será algo de xubuntu?

Comment: Deberías de añadir mas información: salida de los comandos `ifconfig`, `sudo route`, `sudo netstat -a -n -t`, la URL exacta que estás usando en el móvil, y alguna cosilla mas que ya irá saliendo ;-)

Comment: De todas formas, antes de *calentarnos* mas con el tema: para probar las cosas, hay sitios especializados, como [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) (el que yo uso) para facilitar las pruebas desde varios dispositivos, sin problemas de redes, configuración, enrutado, y otras *malas yerbas*.